# It is possible to achieve that the destination collection has different length than source using guava transform?

Tags: java, guava, transformation

I have this issue:

source list - different integers

destination - only even integers source list.

Can I solve this problem using guava transform?

Comment: A filter seems more appropriate...

Comment: Your question title is eerily reminding me of "Has anyone ever been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like?"

Comment: `transform` is an *isomorphism*, which means it doesn't change the cardinality of the collection.

Comment: ok. I inderstood yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  List<Integer>  transList = Collections2.filter(list, new Predicate<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public boolean apply(@Nullable Integer integer) {
                   return integer % 2 == 0;
                }
            });
```

But it is really to make following in 1 step:

source = [1 2 3 4 5 6]

intermediate=[2 4 6]

```
*3
```

destination=[6 12 24]

?

Comment: Or one liner: `return integer % 2 == 0;`

Comment: Thanks. And can you answer the question in my response?

Comment: You could maybe use a FluentIterable, but why not do it in two steps: filter then transform?

Comment: I am novice in Guava. I am investigating this tool

Comment: If you use Java 8 then it's easy: `list.stream().filter(i -> i%2 == 0).map(i -> i * 3).collect(toList());`.